# <Algorithms >Divisor Problem

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Given a the number of divisors, we have to find the first triangle number.

> A triangle number is same as sum of natural numbers.

I had adopted the method of taking prime numbers starting from 2 and permute them so that the number generated matches triangle number.

For example, suppose we are given 5 divisors. I take primes starting from 2 onwards `(2,3,5)` as `N=p1^a1*p2*a2*p3^a3`. Number of divisors are `(a1+1)(a2+1)....` here `2,3,5` can take powers and permuted. Then `n^2+n=2k` (k is the value got from permutation). I check n value to be Integer.

I have not found any efficient algo besides this, does any one has more optimal one?

Comment: Isn't this [problem 12 of Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=12) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse approach. Since n-th triangle number can be found as (n^2 + n)/2, you can just iterate n and for each number count its divisors. Some optimizations:

- (n^2+n)/2 = n(n+1)/2. n and n+1 do not have any common divisors (except for 1), and only one of them is even. Therefore the number of divisors is either multiplied number of divisors of n/2 and n+1, or multiplied number of divisors of n and (n+1)/2.
- number of divisors can be found by the formula you mentioned, therefore you only need a list of prime numbers (get it [here](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/), for example)

This approach seems to be a bit more straightforward and optimal. Moreover, it guarantees that you will find the *first* triangle number.